# K-means clustering on text data without tf-idf preprocessing

Tags: python, k-means

I used k-means to cluster text data without TF-IDF preprocessing to convert text data into numbers.
I can retrieve K-means clustering groups without any problem, but from what I know, isn't that K-means only takes numeric data ?

Can someone explain to me is this occasion, how K-means calculated the distance between text?

The data is a dataframe with thousands of rows, below are some of it. "    Milk Jam     Bread   Apple   Beef    Soda" are the text I clustered. "True" means the item shows in the nth observation.

```
Milk    Jam     Bread   Apple   Beef    Soda
False   True    True    False   False   False
True    True    False   False   False   False
False   False   False   False   True    False
False   False   True    True    False   True
```

My Code

```
# assigning index to items
id_compound_dict = dict(zip(df3.index, list(df3)))
[(k, id_compound_dict[k]) for k in list(id_compound_dict.keys())[0:5]] 

# k-means clustering
n_clusters = 2
kmeans_fit = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters).fit(df3)

#  Checking clustering groups
group = 0   # no n group
ids = np.where(kmeans_fit.labels_ == group)[0] 
names = [id_compound_dict[i] for i in ids]     
names
```

Comment: And where exactly is the text? Just looks like boolean values. You might be loading in `1`s and `0`s.

Comment: @Tomothy32 "    Milk Jam  Bread Apple Beef Soda" are the text that I want to cluster

Comment: Wait so what are all of the `True`s and `False`s for?

Comment: Your data representaion is called *bag of words*. It is not text.

Comment: @Tomothy32 True means the item shows in the nth observation

Comment: @BrunoLubascher thank you. Do you know how K-means cluster bag of words ?

Comment: Bag of words is just a numerical representation of the frequency of each word in a document. So `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Thanks I know bag of words. I meant there must be some way that K-means cluster bag of words, if it was using distance then what kind of distance ?

Comment: Again, `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`. K-means clusters these just like it clusters normal numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

## Data Representation

K-Means expects numerical data and not strings because it computes the Euclidean distances between points.

Possible ways to convert a string document to a numerical representation:

1. Bag of words (BoW)
2. Term frequency (TF)
3. Term frequency-inverse document frequency (TF-IDF)
4. Doc2Vec

These methods for a sort of hierarchy, they Doc2Vec carries out the most information but takes the most effort to compute. BoW takes less effort to compute but carries less information.

**The representation that you have is Bag Of Words.**

## K-Means distance

Classic K-Means (which I assume is the one you have) uses the **Euclidean distance** to converge centroids.
In your case, the `True` and `False` will be treated as `1` and `0` respectively.

The are other variants of K-Means, such as **K-Medians** and **K-Medoids** which can use different distance measures. These can be the Manhattan distance, Cosine distance or any other distance.

One thing you can do as well, is to change the distance function in your algorithm into one that allows string data to be used. You could, for example, use the Levenshtein measure to calculate the distance between points. This way, you could leave your data representation as `string` and not worry about transforming it into numerical representations.

If you are interested in the K-Means variants or changing the distance measure of your algorithm, I recommend you read this [learning unit](https://skratch.valentincalomme.com/learning-units/k-means/). It explains how K-Means works and helps you to implement it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. From my understanding, bag of words is like the pre-processing step for text feature extraction algorithms like Term frequency, TF-IDF. Although BoW looks like 'numbers' but the meaning is actually Boolean values. It doesn't make sense that K-means uses Euclidean distance to calculate the distance between Boolean values. That's why I confused how I still received clustered results !?

Comment: @Osca No problem. The **boolean** values are treated as **numerical** values `0` and `1`. If you think that the *Euclidean distance* is not the way to go, you can change that. Have a look at the link in my answer and you can see how.

Btw, if you feel like your question has been answered, feel free to accept this answer.